# "Stack overflow. Repeat 261929 times[...]" is the error message when I have debugged my code then I do not see any issues so what should I do?

Tags: c#, loops, object, methods, switch-statement

I have coded every line with appropriate things, however, I received an error when I tested after selecting one of the five options from the menu which is prompting the user to choose it for register dog and so on. Therefore, I am unable to recognize any wrong with my code yet I did debug and tested it many times. I do not know what to do with it even though I checked to ensure every case is not overlapped without having a "break;".

In short, I am not sure what to do with my code since I received this specific error message. Once again, I debugged my code and it doesn't show any error except this error message when I run my code.

```
Repeat 261929 times:
--------------------------------
   at Dog.set_Name(System.String)
--------------------------------
   at Dog..ctor(System.String, System.String, Int32, System.String)
   at Program.<Main>$(System.String[])
```

Class:

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Name { get
    {
        return Name;
    }
    set
    {
        Name = value;
    }
    }
    public string Breed { get
    {
        return Breed;
    }
    set
    {
        Breed = value;
    }
    }
    public int Age { get
    {
        return Age;
    }
    set
    {
        Age = value;
    }
    }
    public string Vaccine { get
    {
        return Vaccine;
    }
    set
    {
        Vaccine = value;
    }
    }

    //default constructor
    public Dog()
    {
        Name = "N/A";
        Breed = "N/A";
        Age = -1;
        string [] vaccine = new string[10];
    }

    //parameterized constructor
    public Dog(string name, string breed, int age, string vaccine)
    {
        Name = name;
        Breed = breed;
        Age = age;
        Vaccine = vaccine;
    }
   public string AddVaccine (string vaccine)
   {
         return vaccine;
    }
}
```

Object:

```
//set size of the array for dogs and vaccines
Dog[] dogs = new Dog[20];
string [] vaccine = new string[10];

bool repeat = true;
while(repeat)
{
    //show all menu
    Console.WriteLine("1. Add a new dog\n2. Remove a dog\n3. Add Vaccine\n4. List all dogs\n5. Exit\n");
    Console.Write("Selection: ");
    int selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    switch(selection)
    {
        case 1:

            //ask the user for the info about the car so we can add it to the object
            Console.Write("Enter dog name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter dog breed: ");
            string breed = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter dog age: ");
            int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //finding an available location in the list
            for(int i = 0; i < dogs.Length; i++)
            {
                if(dogs[i] == null)
                {
                    dogs[i] = new Dog(name, breed, age, string.Empty);
                    Console.WriteLine("Dog successfully added");
                    break;
                }      
            }  
            break;
            case 2:
                Console.Write("Enter the dog name:");
                string dogName = Console.ReadLine();
                bool removed = false;
                for(int i = 0; i< dogs.Length; i++)
                {
                    Dog dog = dogs[i];
                    if(dog!=null && dog.Name == dogName)
                    {
                        
                        dog = null;
                        dogs[i] = dog;
                        removed = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} was successful removed", dogName);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (!removed)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} was not found", dogName);
                    }
                }
            break;
            case 3:
                Console.Write("Enter the dog name:");
                string name2 = Console.ReadLine();
                bool added = false;
                for(int i = 0; i< dogs.Length; i++)
                {
                    Dog dog = dogs[i];
                    if(dog!=null && dog.Name == name2)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter the vaccine name:");
                        string vac = Console.ReadLine();
                        if(vac == null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Vaccine not added");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dog.Vaccine = vac;
                            added = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} was successful added", vac);
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    if (!added)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} was not found", name2);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                bool listIsEmpty = true;
                foreach(Dog dog in dogs)
                {
                    if(dog != null)
                    {
                        ShowDogInfo(dog);
                        listIsEmpty = false;
                    }
                }
                if(listIsEmpty)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No dogs in the list");
                }
            break;
            case 5:
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using Rochester Doggie System");
                repeat = false;
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection");
                break;
        }
    }

void ShowDogInfo(Dog dog)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", dog.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Breed: {0}", dog.Breed);
    Console.WriteLine("Age: {0}", dog.Age);
    Console.WriteLine("Vaccine: {0}", dog.Vaccine);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: do you mean I need to separate code by code or make it minimal? I just included in case if someone want to read a whole of code.

Comment: It's much easier to help you if you include the smallest amount of code that reproduces the issue. Please read through making a [mre].

Comment: Can you show your implementation of the Dog class, especially the constructor and the Name property?

Comment: @KlausGütter sure, i have updated so take a look there.

Comment: You have `Name` property, and in `get` and `set` of it, you are reusing it. this causes infinite loop and that results in stackoverflow exception. You should simplify the properties with just `get` and `set`. for example `public string Name {get;set;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Name = value;`: in the setter, you call the setter, which calls the setter etc.
This results in the observed stack overflow.

Change your properties to auto-properties:

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
// etc.
}
```

Comment: I understand now why my code has something missing. Thank you.